# Como retornar um valor importado em uma página JSP para outra?

Tags: java, java-ee, jsp

Tenho duas páginas JSP: em uma ela verifica uma condição de vínculos de clientes, se não possui vínculo, entra em uma função que chama outra JSP para importar os dados do cliente.

Ele até importa os dados mas, quando retorna a JSP que lhe chamou ele não traz logo os dados, tenho q digitar novamente o cliente pra ver seus dados!

Quero saber se existe alguma forma de quando importar e retornar para a JSP anterior ele já trazer os dados e preencher os campos automaticamente?

Segue parte do código da JSP que chama a outra JSP pra importar dados

```
function setar(chave, campo, valorchave, valorcampo, vinculo) {
    if (vinculo == 'N'){
        document.getElementById(chave).value = valorchave;
        document.getElementById(campo).value = valorcampo;
        x.innerHTML = "";
        hide();

        if(campo=="nome")         {
           var jsquery = "<%= query%>";
           //Tira o paciente e coloca o escolhido
           jsquery = replaceParameter(jsquery, "codcli", valorchave);
           document.getElementById("frmcadastrar").action = displayPopup("ativapaciente.jsp?"+jsquery+ "&emp="+empresa,"ativapac",300,500);

        }
    }else{
        document.getElementById(chave).value = valorchave;
        document.getElementById(campo).value = valorcampo;
        x.innerHTML = "";
        hide();

        if(campo=="nome") {
            var jsquery = "<%= query%>";
            jsquery = replaceParameter(jsquery, "codcli",valorchave);
            document.getElementById("frmcadastrar").action = "detalheagenda.jsp?"+jsquery;
            document.getElementById("frmcadastrar").submit();
        }
    }
}
```

e aqui parte da JSP que importa os dados e retorna para a que chamou

```
function gravarPacienteAtivo(){
    if(document.getElementById("cpf").value != "" || document.getElementById("carteira").value != "" || document.getElementById("fone").value != "" ) {                                                               
        var salvar = document.getElementById("frmcadastrar");
        salvar.action+="?codcli="+cod_pac+"&cod_empresa="+empresa;
        salvar.submit();
    }else
        alert("Escolha e preencha uma das informações necessárias.");
    }
}

//função retorna a janela
function iniciar() {          
    if(inf == "1"){ 
        alert("Paciente ativado com sucesso.");
        //Abri a página que abriu esse jsp
        self.close();
        window.opener.location.reload(true);

    } else
        inicio();
    }
}
```

Comment: Pergunta: vc tentou implementar os metodos doPost e doGet. Você pode passar os valores pelo HttpServletRequest.

Comment: Nao tentei, vc pode me explicar como fazer?

Comment: Talvez esse link do FINSLAB possa te ajudar a fazer.. não tenho muita certeza que seja a solução do seu problema mais em todo caso veja... http://finslab.com/negocios-e-trabalho/artigo-1168.html

Comment: Cara, isso não é JSP é javascript! Você quer trazer dados da sua JSP para o Javascript?

Comment: Opa meu caro.
Você tentou passar essas informações por classes mesmo, uma Bean, onde você já faria uma função ajax pra validar e redirecionar pra outra tela(ou o que eu faria, uma modal na mesma tela, dependendo da quantidade de informações)?
Ao meu ver, seria a forma mais adequada, ou pelo menos mais adequada do que a atual.
Caso eu esteja enganado, poderia descrever melhor o seu fluxo de informações, por favor?
Espero ter ajudado.